# Who were the landing platform personnel at the Geonosian command spire?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, attack-of-the-clones

In *Attack of the Clones*, a hive spire served as the command center for the Droid Army fighting in the Battle of Geonosis. A landing platform was located at the spire, from which both the Separatist Council and Count Dooku himself fled after being defeated by the Clone Army of the Republic. On the platform we saw personnel who were not Geonosians (no wings, but funny hats).

[image]

[image]

**Who were they?**

Comment: Neither the novelisation or junior novelisation has anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on images like the one [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Neimoidian_guard) I reckon they are Neimoidian Guards, part of the Trade Federation's presence.

Answer (score 0):

They were **Neimoidian Ground Crewmembers**, personnel for the Trade Federation working as engineers, workers, mechanics and pilots. These ones were assigned to the *Lapiz Cutter*, the personal *Sheathipede*-class transport shuttle/Neimoidian escort shuttle of TF Viceroy Nute Gunray. Some ex-ground crewmembers were also seen on Coruscant at the Outlander Club, former TF employees and regular patrons of night clubs.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this that you could [edit] in such as quotes?